# How to save PageSpeed Insights results to Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, pagespeed

I have a table of urls in BigQuery on which I would like to perform a check of PageSpeed Insights score (or even include the whole response from API in the BigQuery table). I tried to use UDFs for this purpuse, but for now no luck with this. Is there a way of getting the response from:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=https://google.com/&strategy=mobile&key=yourAPIKey
```

to BigQuery table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make API calls from BigQuery UDFs for several reasons. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633292/making-api-call-as-part-of-udf-in-bigquery-possible) for more details about that.

Although there are a few ways to achieve what you want to do, I'd recommend using a [Cloud Dataflow pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/):

1. Read your BigQuery using `BigQueryIO.Read` source
2. In your `ParDo`, call the API you want
3. Write your results back to BigQuery using the `BigQueryIO.Write` sink